# Unable to pip install gingerit

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I want to use `gingerit` package in PyCharm, but I am unable to install it.

I tried this:

```
pip install gingerit
```

But it shows the error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gingerit (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for gingerit
```

[image: error]

Comment: Have you been able to use `pip` to install *anything* in this environment before? How was `pip` installed? Are you sure this exists in the Python Package Index?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/gingerit/ returns a 404 status. This package isn't in PyPI.

Comment: @MichaelRuth is there any way we can use gingerit in pycharm?

Comment: @nitind yes i can install other things with pip install. only gingerit throws error

Comment: Side note: is naming the project `Grammer` a typo, or is it supposed to be ironic?

Answer (score 2):

It appears the `gingerit` distribution was removed from PyPI.  From the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/), the distribution did exist in June 2022 ([archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20220630220402/https://pypi.org/project/gingerit/)). However, its PyPI page has been serving a 404 error least as of October 2023 ([archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20231030064239/https://pypi.org/project/gingerit/)).

It is not clear from the outside why the distribution was removed from PyPI. It's possible that the original author self-deleted it. Or maybe it was removed because it contained malicious code (though it is not listed in the [OpenSSF index of malicious PyPI packages](https://github.com/ossf/malicious-packages/tree/main/malicious)). Or perhaps it was taken down due to copyright violations. Likely only  the original author and/or the PyPI maintainers know.

There does not appear to be any way to install the package now unless you can find an old distribution through third-party channels. The Wayback Machine didn't save any source archives or wheel files from PyPI.

Comment: From your wayback links to PyPi, you can find a link to Github, where you can also see the repository on wayback. Looks like the package only consisted of a single .py file. `https://web.archive.org/web/20221205003237/https://github.com/Azd325/gingerit/blob/main/gingerit/gingerit.py`